# The unusual equations

Tags: pattern

When I entered a number on my calculator from 10 to 99 and then rapidly tap the equal button (nth times) a different  two digit number  appears on the screen. If I rapidly tap the equal button  (nth times) again, the number that I entered before reappears on the screen. This looks like the two numbers are equal for some reason since they alternately reappeared upon tapping of nth times.Even when cleared, the two numbers would match up again if the procedure is repeated. It works for almost all of the numbers from 10 to 99 except 11,14,42,50,88,89. Here are some resulting pairs that were found:

[10==72]    [18==43]    [19==57]    [20==93]    [21==74]    [22==46]    [25==40]    [26==63]    [27==16]    [28==99]

[31==15]    [35==64]    [36==95]    [38==90]    [39==62]    [44==61]    [47==13]    [49==32]    [51==12]    [52==94]

[53==87]    [54==70]    [55==23]    [56==29]    [60==58]    [65==48]    [67==45]    [68==80]    [69==82]    [75==73]

[76==24]    [77==41]    [78==33]    [83==66]    [84==59]    [86==98]    [91==37]    [92==30]    [96==85]    [97==81]

Can you guess what number should result by entering 71 and tapping nth times?

Comment: Can you pardon for mistyped

Comment: @TSLF Hint I can do the [77==14] edit instead. But you mentioned that 14 does not have a pair

Comment: @Sasar Chand. I mistyped 41 as one of the numbers that doesnt work but was on paired [77==41], i edit as it was noticed by humn,thanks,so i corrected to 14 as one of the unworking numbers. The hint state otherwise if the paired 41 is edited to 14 instead and leaving the 41 as one of the unworking number.

Comment: To clarify, are we expected to work out 'n' too, or does the use of 'nth' here just mean 'a particular number of times which is always the same for any starting number but whose exact value does not matter for this puzzle?

Comment: @stiv-to simplify nth times .. say twice only. nothing to do  for this puzzle (Note: no calculator is programmed to do so)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that entering 71 and tapping equals repeatedly should result in the number:

> **17**

Why? Well note firstly that in each pair of 'equivalent' numbers:

> the two numbers both use the same total number of segments on an LCD display. For example, '10==72' since:
>  - '1' uses 2 segments and '0' uses 6, making 8 segments in total;
>  - '7' uses 3 segments and '2' uses 5, again making 8 segments in total.
>
>  [image]

Note that in the range 10-99, there are 90 numbers in all. These can be split into the following categories:

> Numbers with 4 segments total: **11**. (n=1)
>  Numbers with 5 segments total: 17, 71. (n=2)
>  Numbers with 6 segments total: **14**, 41, 77. (n=3)
>  Numbers with 7 segments total: 12, 13, 15, 21, 31, 47, 51, 74. (n=8)
>  Numbers with 8 segments total: 10, 16, 19, 27, 37, 44, 57, 61, 72, 73, 75, 91. (n=12)
>  Numbers with 9 segments total: 18, 24, 34, **42**, 43, 45, 54, 67, 70, 76, 79, 81, 97. (n=13)
>  Numbers with 10 segments total: 22, 23, 25, 32, 33, 35, 40, 46, 49, 52, 53, 55, 64, 78, 87, 94. (n=16)
>  Numbers with 11 segments total: 20, 26, 29, 30, 36, 39, 48, **50**, 56, 59, 62, 63, 65, 84, 92, 93, 95. (n=17)
>  Numbers with 12 segments total: 28, 38, 58, 60, 66, 69, 82, 83, 85, 90, 96, 99. (n=12)
>  Numbers with 13 segments total: 68, 80, 86, **89**, 98. (n=5)
>  Numbers with 14 segments total: **88**. (n=1)
>
>  Notice that for any of the pairs given in the puzzle, if you look up either of the two numbers among these categories you will find its partner in the same category.

See also that for the 6 'partnerless' numbers listed in the puzzle (11, 14, 42, 50, 88, 89):

> each of these falls into a category which has an *odd number* of items (bolded in the list above). These are effectively 'odd ones out' - numbers left over once all the other numbers in their same-number-of-segments category have been paired up. (For now I can see no clear reason why each particular pairing exists - more it seems that the items within each category have just been paired up arbitrarily - of course I may have missed something systematic here...)

To add further weight to this working hypothesis, notice that if we note down all the numbers paired up or explicitly listed as odd-ones-out, we are left with:

> only 4 unused numbers: 71 (the number we are supposed to pair), 17, 34 and 79. Clearly, 71 must pair with one of the remaining three.

To find its partner, we then note that:

> both 34 and 79 can be made from 9 segments, and so are likely paired together, while 71 and 17 *are the only two 2-digit numbers which require just 5 segments to be written on an LCD display*. Thus everything in this puzzle fits together consistently, and - regardless of whether there is a system to choosing which two numbers within a segment category are paired together - **71 must be paired with 17**.

Comment: PS Yes, I've noticed I've fallen foul of [RAS syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome) here... ;-)